# Unity - VR - App Switcher?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

We have a bunch of VR demos and apps we've created with Unity. We want to put them all on one machine and use a launcher to allow users to view the various demos without help.

We want someone to be able to do everything while using the Vive. So, they see the demo/app menu in VR - then can select one, view it, and return to the launcher menu to view another.

I know I can launch other .exe's from Unity - but can I start one VR app from another, and then return gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

I think that launching a new exe will result in a bad user experience. The only solution that can prevent this is to export every game into a package and then to merge all the game packages together in a new project where you add your launcher. In case there might be conflicts in your scripts just give every script in every game an individual namespace:

```
 namespace FirstGame
 {
     public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
     {
      // your code here
     }
 }
```